В данном случае "хотя" принадлежит придаточной части, в которой есть слово "когда"?
То есть нужно ли ставить запятую после "хотя"?
перебрал 5 ручек, и все они перестали писать, когда я пытался работать с ними, хотя когда я чиркал ими для теста, то работали нормально

«хотя когда я чиркал ими для теста, то работали нормально»
После «хотя» у вас двойной союз «когда...то». В этом случае «хотя» и «когда» разделять запятой не нужно, потому что выбросить придаточное предложение «когда я чиркал ими для теста» без преобразования всего предложения невозможно. (Вариант « хотя то работали нормально» звучит странно).
Вариант без двойного союза в Корпусе русского языка представлен и с запятой и без. Но с двойным союзом вариант может быть только один.
